# May the compiler silently convert from const to const& and vice versa?

Tags: c++

The thought behind this is that the value won't be changed so that we don't need to care about the memory adress.

Of course there are special cases like (maybe only) polymorphism where this is not possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more (preferably in code)? Where do you envision such a conversion?

Comment: Silently convert like in [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization)?

Comment: Compiler doesn't need to convert between `const` and `const&` explicitly, but it may generate same code for both cases as long as it doesn't violate constraints.

Comment: I looked at this question for something like int, bool, etc, where a const reference would be bigger than the type itself but provide the same functionality. Any enlightenment there? (From Godbolt testing, looks like this type of optimization does not occur.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value copy of an object might not be taken if `const&` is substituted for `const`.

If that has a side effect then the compiler is not allowed to make the substitution.

In this respect, the rule differs from *return value optimisation* where a value copy is allowed to be dropped even if there are side effects.

Comment: So to be clear, when choosing between auto const and auto const&, the former is better because it encompasses both?